# how to check how many words can be made?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

how many words with length 30 can I create using only 0,1,2 when we use at least 12 2's and the difference of times we use 0 and 1 is 2 at most?
it is possible not to use 0's or 1's or both if the difference is 2 at most.

to start with, I arranged 12 2's so we have 30!/12!*18! options, I tried to split into different cases on the relations with the 0's and 1's but it lead nowhere. I got 5 arrangements: when n0=n1||n0=n1+1||n0=n1+2||n0=n1-1||n0=n1-2||. and for each arrangement, I got different possibilities 1.10! 2.9! 3.9! 4.10! 5.11!. but I know I got some duplicates in each one.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, for clarity...are you specifying the length of these words?  If not, the answer would seem to be "infinitely many".

Comment: Pl. edit in your efforts even if they seem to be leading nowhere.

Comment: Based on your constraints, you may have 12x0+8x1+10x2, or 12x0+9x1+9x2 or 12x0+10x1+8x2  or 13x0+8x1+9x2 or ... ...   , something like 30 or 40 patterns. For each pattern, you can calculate the number of words. And then calculate the sum. It seems the best method. So, do you know how to calculate the number of words with $a$ 0, $b$ 1 and $c$ 2 ?

Comment: Does the word have to include at least one of $0$ and at least one of $1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose a total of $12$ two's are used when constructing the word.
Then, there are $30-12=18$ remaining positions in which we can place $1$'s or $0$'s. There are three ways to write $18$ as a sum of two positive integers having a difference of at most $2$: $18=10+8=9+9=8+10$. We can view the first and second elements in our sum as the number of positions occupied by $1$'s and $0$'s respectively. Thus, it's easy to see that in this case there are $\binom{30}{12,10,8}+\binom{30}{12,9,9}+\binom{30}{12,8,10}$ possible words.

Taking an example where an odd number of two's are used, we can see that we only get a sum of two multinomial coefficients. To illustrate, if $13$ two's are used, there are $\binom{30}{13,9,8}+\binom{30}{13,8,9}$ possible words.

By similar logic, we calculate the number of possible words when $13,14,\dots,30$ two's are used in the word. Therefore, in total, there are

$\sum\limits_{k\hspace{ .1cm}even, 12\le k\le30}{\big(2\cdot\binom{30}{k,\frac{30-k}{2}+1,\frac{30-k}{2}-1}+\binom{30}{k,\frac{30-k}{2},\frac{30-k}{2}}\big)}\hspace{ .1cm}+\hspace{ .1cm}\sum\limits_{k\hspace{ .1cm}odd, 12\le k\le30}{\big(2\cdot\binom{30}{k,\frac{30-k+1}{2},\frac{30-k-1}{2}}\big)}$

ways to construct the word. This sum could probably be simplified further, or just computed directly, but I'll just leave the answer as is. Here, we use the convention that a multinomial coefficient equals zero if one or more of its components are negative.

Comment: no, we have at least 12 2's

Comment: @yahelamity Please read the solution again. The first two cases are used as examples to establish the logic used in the calculations. The final calculation accounts for every possible number of 2's the word could have; namely, from 12 to 30.

Comment: @user2661923 Fixed. Thanks for pointing out!